# Blocking SOME but not all endpoints in Wordpress rest api

Tags: endpoint, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating a REACT app that uses wordpress as a backend through the rest API. I am using the Simple-JWT-Login plugin to handle the register, login, authentication, and it works perfectly.

I want to block non-logged in users from accessing the /wp/v2/posts endpoint. I know I can do this by doing something like:

```
    add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
      if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
      }
      if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'You are not currently logged in.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
      }
      if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_admin', 'You are not entitled to view that.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
      }
      return $result;
    });
```

However that blocks all endpoints, including `?rest_route=/simple-jwt-login/v1/auth` and `?rest_route=/simple-jwt-login/v1/users` which are the ones from the Simple-JWT-Login plugin used for registering and authenticating users. Therefore users end up in a catch 22 whereby they can't login unless they are already logged in!

Is there a way of modifying the above code to block just the wp/v2/posts/ endpoint, or, alternatively, of effectively whitelisting the registering and authenticating endpoints?

Many thanks for any ideas!

Have searched on here and elsewhere but can't find a solution.

Comment: Hello, while exploring the wp rest API i've encountered the same problem. Did you finally find a solution ? I'm wandering how to create a whitelist of endpoints to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry for late reply - din't see notification. No, unfortunately I never got anywhere with that. If you have found a solution in the meantime, would be great to know!

Answer (score 0):

You could always check for the url before showing the error  with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but that might become a pain to add all your allowed urls in a if check.

I like to use apache_request_headers with preg_match to check for a Bearer Token and if the current request has the correct bearer token, show the results. Otherwise you would throw a error. I can't guarantee its 100% safe or the correct way to do it but it works pretty well for a super basic simple system.

Something like the below code might work for someone:

```
add_filter("rest_authentication_errors", function ($result) {

    if (!empty($result)) {
        return $result;
    }

    $headers = apache_request_headers();
  
    $matches = array();

    $currentToken = "PUT YOUR BEARER TOKEN HERE";
    $pattern = $currentToken."/i";
        
    preg_match('/Bearer '. $pattern, $headers['Authorization'], $matches);

        
    if(isset($matches)){
            
        $token = $matches[0];
         
    
        if($token == 'Bearer ' . $currentToken){
        
        
            return $result;
        
        
        } else {
        
             return new WP_Error( 'no_auth_found', 'You are not currently logged in.' , array( 'status' => 401));
        
        }
        
    }

});
```